# Is there a way to turn off the ad popup that appears when you close a Steam game?

Tags: steam

After you're done playing a game on Steam, there's an annoying popup that appears advertising other Steam games.  I'm perfectly capable of finding my own games that I would like to play.  Is there a way to disable this popup?

Answer (score 74, accepted):

It's actually quite easy to disable them. In the Settings window, go to the Interface tab. There's an option at the bottom to disable these notifications.

[image: Notify me about new and upcoming releases.]

I do believe that this is an option they added in semi-recently, because I've been using Steam for a long time and I've never seen it before a few days ago.